# Como transformar string em array

Tags: php

Recebo um resultado dessa forma:

```
"POLYGON((-22.886145457836463 -43.118764097835, -22.88643210096987 -43.118324215556555, -22.886694032959 -43.117846782351904, -22.886763222456636 -43.11767512097))"
```

Preciso transformar nesta forma:

```
lat=> -22.886145457836463, lng=>-43.118764097835,
lat=> -22.88643210096987, lng=>-43.118324215556555,
lat=> -22.886694032959, lng=>-43.117846782351904,
lat=> -22.886763222456636, lng=>-43.117846782351907
```

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar funções basicas de manipulação de string.

Use a função `str_replace()` para retirar os parenteses, e alguns espaços indesejáveis depois da virgula, deixando apenas os valores.

Depois utilize a função `explode()` para subdividir esta string em um array, e com o auxilio de um `foreach` adicione os itens ao array final com os valores:

```
$latLongString = "POLYGON((-22.886145457836463 -43.118764097835, -22.88643210096987 -43.118324215556555,-22.886694032959 -43.117846782351904, -22.886763222456636 -43.11767512097))";

$latLongString = str_replace(["POLYGON((","))"], "", $latLongString); // remover os parenteses deixando somente os valores;
$latLongString = str_replace(", ", ",", $latLongString); // remover os espaços depois das virgulas;

$arrayLatLong = array();

$valores = explode(",",$latLongString);
foreach($valores as $subVal){
  $latLong = explode(" ",$subVal);
  $arrayLatLong[]=array("lat"=> $latLong[0],"lng"=>$latLong[1]);
}
```

Desta maneira a sua saída será um array com este formato:

```
array (size=4)
  0 =>
    array (size=2)
      'lat' => string '-22.886145457836463' (length=19)
      'lng' => string '-43.118764097835' (length=16)
  1 =>
    array (size=2)
      'lat' => string '-22.88643210096987' (length=18)
      'lng' => string '-43.118324215556555' (length=19)
  2 =>
    array (size=2)
      'lat' => string '-22.886694032959' (length=16)
      'lng' => string '-43.117846782351904' (length=19)
  3 =>
    array (size=2)
      'lat' => string '-22.886763222456636' (length=19)
      'lng' => string '-43.11767512097' (length=15)
```

Comment: Boa Tarde.

agradeço a ajuda.
 desculpe mais ainda não entendi muito bem

Comment: Vou editar a resposta com uma solução completa pra você ver.

Comment: Ruhan tem como retirar também o {"area":"

Comment: @CarlosAlexandreRRamos não compreendi, como assim retirar o area?

Comment: Boa Tarde Senhores.

Estou recebendo uma array:
{
    "lat": "[{\"area\":\"-22.88975203013098",
    "lng": "-43.12695211119432"
  },

Como retiro o {\"area\":\"

Comment: Para retirar qualquer parte da sua string utilize a funcao str_replace, no primeiro parametro você deve passar qual parte da string deseja reescrever, no segundo pelo que quer rescrever (nesse caso uma string vazia), e por ultimo a string em si.

Por exemplo:
`str_replace('area', '', $suaString);`